# How to invoke babel, a US-English exception list, and hyphenrules properly?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, german, english

Let's assume we care about the proper hyphenation of a few English words in a multi-lingual document in which the main language is not English. These few words happen to find themselves in `ushyphex.tex`; without loading this hyphenation dictionary, the hyphenation would be wrong or incomplete even in the scope of `\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{…}`. How to load an exception dictionary for the US English properly and in which order with respect to the other language-related stuff?  Here's what we do now:

```
\documentclass[USenglish,british,ngerman]{article}% make languages class options so that certain other packages (e.g., cleveref) can pick them up properly.
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[USenglish,british,main=ngerman]{babel}% say which language is the main one.
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=ngerman-x-latest]{ngerman}% load the most recent hyphenation patterns for the main language. Anything comparable for US English? If not:
\selectlanguage{USenglish}
\input{ushyphex}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[ngerman,noabbrev]{cleveref}% cf. § 10 in the manual of cleveref
\begin{document}
Beliebiger deutscher Text \textellipsis% This is an arbitrary main-language text simply for the purpose of demonstrating that the main document language is NOT English.
\showhyphens{\foreignlanguage{USenglish}{algebraically}}% a random exception not covered by current babel, e.g., “process”, “atherosclerosis”, …
\end{document}
```

As expected, we get `al-ge-bra-i-cal-ly` on the console.  Is the way of loading `ushyphex.tex` sandwiched into `\selectlanguage{USenglish}…\selectlanguage{ngerman}` correct™? Or should we better say `{\selectlanguage{USenglish}\input{ushyphenex}}` or something similar? Or is there any babel-specific equivalent of `ushyphex.tex`?  E.g., should I better invoke the package `hyph-utf8` or `hyphenex` instead?  If there is no extra babel-specific exception list for English: is the position of loading `ushyphex.tex` correct™?

Comment: \hyphenation always adds to the current language so it doesn't matter where you input it so long as the current language is 0 at that point

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks! And I'm also unsure whether other packages and commands in the preamble of my example reset or alter the current hyphenation exceptions and rules in a way that would interfere with loading `ushyphex` for the language 0. Put differently, does loading `ushyphex` for the language 0 commute with the other commands and packages? I'm also unsure what would be the proper™ way to load `ushyphex` for the language 0.

Comment: you can't remove hyphenation exceptions once added.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle However, presumably, issuing `\hyphenation` twice for the same word has the result that only the second occurrence counts. E.g., `\hyphenation{algebraically}\hyphenation{al-ge-bra-i-cal-ly}` has a different effect than `\hyphenation{al-ge-bra-i-cal-ly}\hyphenation{algebraically}`. It might hypothetically happen that the loaded packages interfere with `ushyphex` this way.

Comment: it might, some package might have `\def\input{boo}` as well, but some things are not worth worrying about:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I consider it much more unlikely that a package redefines `\input` in comparison to potential (re)defintions of word hyphenations by language-related or language-aware packages listed in my MWE.

Comment: sure but you can not do anything about it or even detect it from within tex. unlike checking for macro definition clashes you have no way to detect which exceptions have been added.  So it may theoretically happen but you can not detect it or avoid it so no point worrying about it. hyphenations are subjective anyway

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Even if I cannot detect redefinitions myself, I could ask folks here at TeX Stackexchange, and they might (or might not) say stuff such as, “Dude, first do this and then do that because I know that the lines so-and-so might interact in an unintended way”.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  As for hyphenations, I consider ushyphex partially wrong. E.g., `funk-tsional` is a misprint or a transcription of a foreign word and simply shouldn't be there in any case! If it's a German adjective, it should be simply typeset as `\foreignlanguage{ngerman}{funktional}` in the main text. If it's a transcription of a Russian noun, it should be typeset as `funk\-tsi\-o\-nal` in the main text because of https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/функционал. The main breaking point is after the stem "funktsi".